# Как в tkinter нажатием кнопки заставить работать 2 виджета?

Tags: python, tkinter

Реализую игру:

в одном поле tk.Text пользователь пишет вопрос и нажимает под ним кнопку "Спросить", а во втором поле tk.Text программа выводит ответы, случайным образом выбранные из имеющегося списка.

Написал код, который к выводу ответов не приводит. Более того, ловлю ошибку: `TypeError: call_funcs() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Что не так?

Код:

```
# Обработчик вопроса пользователя 
def questionQuery(question):
    question = text_box_question.get('1.0', tk.END) # читаем текст из виджета text_box_question
    time.sleep(2)

# Функция возврата случайных ответов
def answerQuery():
    text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Хмм...' + '\n') # и выводим в виджет text_box_answer
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(2)
    text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Я заглядываю за повороты судьбы, чтобы узнать о грядущем' + '\n')
    window.update_idletasks()
    window.after(2000, lambda: text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, random.choice(responses) + '\n'))

# Функция для создания цепи событий по одному клику кнопки 
def call_funcs():
    questionQuery()
    answerQuery()

# привязываем к кнопке обработку события
button_ask.bind('<Button>', call_funcs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо правильно определять функцию-обработчик события. У неё должен быть один обязательный аргумент (см. [документацию](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/event-handlers.html)).

```
def call_funcs(event):
  ...
```